# Verificando se existe resultado na query

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá, preciso verificar se existe uma resposta para minha query. Caso exista, deve exibir um codigo HTML exibindo os dados do banco. Caso contrario deve notificar que não existe resultado. Como faço essa seleção?

Exemplo:

```
$sql = "select * from cronograma WHERE equipe='".$equipe."' AND datas='".$data."' "; 
$cronograma = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

//nesse ponto deve verifiar se existe resultado
if($cronograma = existe){
//exibe resultado da tabela}
else{ echo "Não existe resultado";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser saber se a query obteve algum resultado, maior que 0. Você pode usar o `mysqli_num_rows` para contar a quantidade de linhas.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($cronograma) > 0){
  // faça algo
}else{ echo "Não existe resultado";}
```

Mas se você quiser saber apenas se houve sucesso na conexão, basta fazer isso:

```
if($cronograma){
   // faça algo
} else {
  // verifica o erro
  if(mysqli_errno($conexao) == 1064) echo "erro de sintaxe";
}
```

Veja a [lista com numeros dos erros do mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html) que você pode usar.